# Comment deletion...was it offensive?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

There's a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300139/what-is-the-c-sharp-code-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number-with) where a person is asking how to re-write a bit of code.  I and one other person had provided responses, but were confused why the code needed to be rewritten.  The OP then posted that the question was for an interview.  I deleted my answer and posted a comment that read something along the lines explaining why (that I didn't feel comfortable posting "answers" to questions based on interviews.)

Now the comment has disappeared...but I'm not clear why.  I'm guessing it was marked as offensive...though I can't tell for sure.  It kind of surprises me, since I tried to be pretty neutral in explaining why I was deleting my answer, and the OPs response seemed a bit more provocative than my statement...but assuming that's what happened, I guess that's the flagger's perogative.

But I don't really know for sure.  I haven't received any notification that something was deleted as offensive...is there some way to tell?  If I've posted something offensive that would be good to know.  Or, alternatively, if it was deleted for another reason that should concern me, that would probably be good to know as well.

I don't actually care much about the comment...but am curious about notifications so I can possibly adjust in the future.

Additionally, is there supposed to be some kind of notification when a comment is flagged?  It seems like it would be useful.  I mean, if I get one of these a year, I chalk it up to the nature of the web.  If I get a one a week, I should look at adjusting my persona.

Comment: I don't know about your comment or why it was deleted, but I did find the OP's `hhahahahaha hahahahha hahahahha hahahahah I was able to read it` response to be obnoxious.

Comment: @DavidRobinson flagging your comment as offensive.

Comment: Keep in mind pretty much any comment can be deleted at any time for any reason.  Valuable content should not remain in comments for extended periods of time, if they ought to remain, the information should eventually work itself into questions or answers.

Comment: @Servy Sure.  I was just thinking that it might be useful to explain to him why an answer he was looking at suddenly disappeared, and why he might not get many answers in general.  That wouldn't really be appropriate for an answer or modifying his question.

Comment: @beska Yep, it doesn't fall into the category of information that's "valuable content that needs to be maintained", so it doesn't belong in a question/answer.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough...that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your comment was:

> I'm removing my answer. I don't feel comfortable with giving "answers" to interview questions

It was deleted by a diamond moderator.  The flagging history doesn't indicate specifically which comments were flagged, or by whom.

Comments are for clarification of a post, or asking for clarification.  Any other use subjects them to deletion.  In this particular case it's unclear whether your comment adds any value, since it is readily apparent when an answer is deleted, and you don't explain why you're not comfortable answering.

Comment flags are not kept on your permanent record. If SE is not concerned about a single comment that got an offensive flag, neither should you be.

Comment: Thanks for posting the original comment (I had no way to recreate the exact wording.)  

Fair enough.  I thought the reasoning about why I wouldn't feel comfortable with such things would be self evident but apparently not and, as you imply, it may not have added any value.  I guess what confused me was the fact that it was removed, but his response and my other comment (which was arguably slightly more snarky, and less helpful) was not.  Seemed a bit odd.  But *shrug*.

Comment: That said, before I accept this answer, I'm more curious about the notifications aspect: is that something that has been considered as a feature?

Comment: No, there's no notifications on comments.  They just disappear, without warning.  Comments are meant to be temporary, with limited tracking and utility.  They were given just enough functionality to allow clarifications and notifications; deleted comments have no functionality at all, except that they are kept in a log so that moderators can see them (at one time, *that* didn't even exist).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't worried about being notified that it was deleted. More if it was flagged as offensive...that, I *would* want to know about.

Comment: @beska: Comment flags are not kept on your permanent record.  If SE is not concerned about a single comment that got an offensive flag, neither should you be.

Comment: I think you should add that last comment to your answer...I think it nails the essence of what I was wondering about.